# How to "reset" a game when farm keys with friends

Tags: diablo-iii

Here is the issue:

1. MP must be more than 1
2. It must be a party

What happen is after I kill the keywarden, I would leave the game. However, there is no option to start a new game. There is only an option to resume the old game.

So if I resume the old game, my NV is still 5. Yet there is no enemy around.

How can I restart everything so I can get more keys again?

Comment: Are you the party leader?  Everyone has to leave the game, and THEN you can change quest to reset it.  Otherwise, the game thinks, "Oh, you left by accident.  All your friends are still here, come on back!"

Comment: Yes I am the party leader.

Comment: Exactly what @fbueckert said: all party members must leave the game before you can change the quest or start a different game. This allows party members to temporarily exit the game and, for instance, buy something in the AH and come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have everyone leave the game, and then restart it.  This will reset all the monsters, including the Key Wardens.

However, you will also lose your NV stacks, and have to get them back before killing the Key Warden.

It is important that *everyone* in the party leaves the game.  The game only "resets" after everyone is out.  Otherwise, anyone coming back in will maintain their NV stacks and find that the encounters (including Key Wardens) have not reset.

Comment: You can just leave party and start again on your own ... no need for everyone to be out ...

Comment: @giskou So if you and I are in the same game, and we kill the Key Warden, you can portal, log out, log back in, and the Key Warden will respawn while I'm standing there?  I don't believe that is true, but I'll try and test it tonight.

Comment: I said start on you own, new game, not leave party and rejoin party. Leave altogether and resume the game on you own

Comment: @Giskou If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying: start in a multiplayer group, kill key warden, leave multiplayer group, and either join a different multiplayer group or start a new single player game. As I understand it, the question is asking about how to reset the monsters with the same group, not how to leave and start a different group.

Answer (score 0):

From [Patch 1.0.5 – v.1.0.5.12480 (Oct 16, 2012)](http://www.diablowiki.com/Diablo_III_Patches#Patch_1.0.5) Blizzard "fixed" the Party behavior

> Nephalem Valor stacks are now restored whenever a player rejoins the
>   last multiplayer game he/she was disconnected from

also

> Multiplayer
>
> - Leaving a multiplayer game will no longer remove you from the party
>     This means that players can leave the game to browse the Auction House
>     or switch characters without being removed from the
>     group (picking a hardcore character or a character not eligible to go
>     back into the game, however, will disable the "Resume Game" button)
> - To leave a party while in-game, right-click on your hero portrait and
>     select "Leave Game & Party"
> - To leave a party while in the hero screen, right-click on your hero
>     and select "Leave Party"

It didn't use to be like this ... but ...

Comment: -1 This doesn't actually answer the question.  The OP is asking *How to reset keywardens while in multiplayer games*. The answer you provided merely explains why NV stacks are maintained when not resetting a multiplayer game.

Comment: If you leave the party and re-enter you get back all the monsters ...